# unable passing multiple actions to notification action intent

Tags: android

Be informed, we are trying to send notification with a button using Addaction. The button Start has a intent that directly opens a url in a webview, which works perfectly fine with code given below

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("uri", uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //int notification_id = nid!=null ? Integer.parseInt(nid) : MainActivity.ASWV_FCM_ID;

        int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        int notification_id=m;

        Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(this, ButtonReceiver.class);
        buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId",notification_id);

//Create the PendingIntent
        PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, buttonIntent,0);

        String channelId = MainActivity.asw_fcm_channel;
        Uri soundUri=Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/pristine");


        NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, tag, pendingIntent).build();
        NotificationCompat.Action action1 = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Dismiss", btPendingIntent).build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.asw_fcm_channel)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .addAction(action)
                .addAction(action1)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);


            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();


            // Configure the notification channel.

            mChannel.setDescription("Common notifications");
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.setSound(soundUri, attributes);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        }
        
        
            Notification noti = notificationBuilder1.build();
            noti.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notificationBuilder1.build());
```

**Update:**

I'm sorry but i'm not actually a expert or a regular coder in android java, so you gotta help me here a little bit more. I have passed on my notification id down in the code, but the problem here is how do i invoke removeNotification in the pendingIntent which also carries my url to where the link will go onclick

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("uri", uri);
intent.putExtra("notificationId",notification_id);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

public static void removeNotification(int notification_id) {
            try {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

But we also like the notification to be dismissed simultaneously onclick. We tried using .setAutocancel (true) and notification flags like FlAG_AUTO_CANCEL, but the button just does first action right of going into webview url and not cancelling the notification.

Shall appreciate should you help us out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Send the notification id in the intent to activity and use the code to cancel.

    public static void removeNotification(Context context, int notification_id) {
            try {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 Timber.d(e);
            }
        }

Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent.hasExtra("notificationID")) {
                removeNotification(context, intent.getIntExtra("notificationID", 0));
            }
```

Comment: Nope its not working. The intent which redirects to uri works but the notification is not cancelled out.

Comment: Sharing your code helps to rectify the error.

Comment: Added the entire notification code. Please check

Comment: Send the notification id in the intent to activity and use the code to cancel ----

public static void removeNotification(Context context, int notification_id) {
        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             Timber.d(e);
        }
    }

Comment: Code is bit messy in the comments, could you please edit your answer.

Comment: I have edited the code, call the remove notification method in the activity you are calling from notification action and pass the notification ID

Comment: Added an update, please check

Comment: Place the remove notification method in the MainActivity class and call the method inside onCreate

Comment: Its working fine naveen. Both actions url direct and notification cancellation happening simultaneously. Thanks allot, but one problem here is when the app is open and notification comes, nor the url intent works or notification is cancelled out.  i don't know where is the error.

Comment: add intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); and try.

Comment: Did add that flag. Didn't work. So based on other resources, i added android:taskAffinity="", it worked partially, the url and notification dialog were closed but, a new window opened up of same app instead of loading in existing window. It meant i was having two windows of same app in my device